# keep the extra whitespaces in display of pandas dataframe in jupyter notebook

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

In jupyter notebook, extra whitespaces  in dataframe are removed. But sometime that is not preferred, e.g.

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['a   b','c'],'B':[1,2]})
df
```

The result I get:

```
|   | A   | B |
|---|-----|---|
| 0 | a b | 1 |
| 1 | c   | 2 |
```

But I want:

```
|   | A     | B |
|---|-------|---|
| 0 | a   b | 1 |
| 1 | c     | 2 |
```

Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: does `print(df)` work or do you need the style as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually HTML: pandas dutifully write all the spaces into the HTML markup (the front end format used by Jupyter Notebook). HTML, by default, collapses multiple adjacent whitespaces into one. Use the [`style`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) object to change this:

```
df.style.set_properties(**{'white-space': 'pre'})
```

You unfortunately can't change the default render style of a DataFrame yet. You can write a function to wrap that line:

```
def print_df(df):
    return df.style.set_properties(**{'white-space': 'pre'})

print_df(df)
```