# Way to show multiple spaces in Pandas Dataframe on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

When displaying Pandas Dataframe object on notebook, multiple spaces are shown as single space. And I cannot copy multiple spaces.

I would like to show all spaces as they are and copy a string of them.

Any way to do so?

```
display(pd.DataFrame([["ab c", "ab  c"], ["ab   c", "ab    c"]]))
```

Actual

```
    0     1   
0   ab c  ab c
1   ab c  ab c
```

My expectation

```
    0       1     
0   ab c    ab  c
1   ab   c  ab    c
```

Comment: For me working correctly.

Comment: `print(df)` yields as expected. `df` on its own produces the first result (unsure why, probably that's your case too?). Though `df.values` the underlying values do contain the expected spacing

Comment: Thanks. Sorry actually I use `display`. not `print`. I updated my question

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: I use Kaggle and Colab notebook. I see this problem on both

Comment: Well. `df.values` is what you expect, right?

Comment: `df.values` shows spaces. That's great. However my df is very big so I'd like to use `display`. If I can find good display option, that would be wonderful

Comment: well if you're just copying try `df.to_clipboard()` that should solve your issue

Comment: Thanks. But I'd like to copy a small part of big df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been answered in a different context:

[keep the extra whitespaces in display of pandas dataframe in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562191/keep-the-extra-whitespaces-in-display-of-pandas-dataframe-in-jupyter-notebook)

```
def print_df(df):
    return df.style.set_properties(**{'white-space': 'pre'})

print_df(df)
```