# Python Panads, how do I can keep whitespaces of the cell values with read_excel?

Tags: python, pandas

I have Excel table with cell values in `A` column that contains whitespaces at the beginning (see also piture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvomp.png)):

```
Все населення.................
 Міське населення.............
 Сільське населення...........
  СІМФЕРОПОЛЬ(міськрада)......
   Міське населення...........
    м. СІМФЕРОПОЛЬ............
```

I read contents of the table with [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) method:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file11, sheet_name=sheet, skiprows=9, usecols="A,D:E,G:H", dtype={"А": "str"})
```

but during the reading process it strips cell values, so that in the resulting dataframe (pic. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmwKY.png)) leading spaces are missing, even when I had explicitly indicated datatype of column `A`.

I also tried to use a simple converter function:

```
def savespaces(f):
    return f.__repr__()

df = pd.read_excel(
    file11, sheet_name=sheet, skiprows=9, usecols="A,D:E,G:H", converters={"А": savespaces})
```

but is has no desired effect too--it kept only one space for every cell text starting with 1, 2, 3 or more spaces--regardless of count of spaces in raw Excel data (see pic. [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC88B.png)).

These spaces are crucial for me, so I would to keep them.

[image: Excel data]
[image: Result dataframe]
[image]

**UPDATE:** As @dm2 mentioned below in his comment, "jupyter notebook it doesn't display them [spaces] when printing the whole df, but printing individual values the spaces are obviously there". With this update, the issue became more clear: Jupyter notebook uses HTML styles and display several spaces as one space accordingly. So problem has a different context, and has an answer here:

[keep the extra whitespaces in display of pandas dataframe in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58562191/2163109)

Comment: Cannot replicate using pandas 1.2.1. On a jupyter notebook it doesn't display them when printing the whole df, but printing individual values the spaces are obviously there. On a command prompt it shows spaces both printing whole df and individual values.

Comment: @dm2 thank you for tip, I explored context and found that is the HTML markup. I'll update question and include your addition.